Cloud Translation Create a glossary ERROR
Version:"google/cloud-translate": "^1.13"
This is the sample code of the document
use Google\ApiCore\ApiException;
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
use Google\Cloud\Translate\V3\GcsSource;
use Google\Cloud\Translate\V3\Glossary;
use Google\Cloud\Translate\V3\Glossary\LanguageCodesSet;
use Google\Cloud\Translate\V3\GlossaryInputConfig;
use Google\Cloud\Translate\V3\TranslationServiceClient;

require "vendor/autoload.php";

$secret_path = "*****.json";
$projectId = "*****";


putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS={$secret_path}");

$location = "us-central1";
$language_codes = ["zh-CN","en"];



$storage = new StorageClient();
$dataContent = [["六","sex"]];
$glossaryId = sprintf("translation%d",rand(1000,9999));
$objectName = $glossaryId.".csv";
try {
    $bucket = $storage->bucket("trans_text");
    $bucket->upload(getCSVContents($dataContent, $language_codes), [
        'name' => $objectName,
        'metadata' => ['contentType' => 'text/csv']
    ]);
   $gsutil_uri = sprintf('gs://%s/%s', "trans_text", $objectName);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
    exit();
}

function getCSVContents($data, $header)
{
    $output = fopen('php://temp', 'w');
    fputcsv($output,$header);
    foreach ($data as $v) {
        fputcsv($output, $v);
    }
    rewind($output);
    $contents = stream_get_contents($output);
    fclose($output);
    return $contents;
}



// Create a client.
$translationServiceClient = new TranslationServiceClient();
$formattedParent = $translationServiceClient::locationName($projectId,$location);
$glossaryName = $translationServiceClient::glossaryName($projectId,$location,$glossaryId);

$language_codes_set = new LanguageCodesSet();
$language_codes_set->setLanguageCodes($language_codes);

$gcs_source = (new GcsSource())->setInputUri($gsutil_uri);
$input_config = (new GlossaryInputConfig())->setGcsSource($gcs_source);
$glossary = (new Glossary())->setName($glossaryName)->setInputConfig($input_config)->setLanguageCodesSet($language_codes_set);


try {
    $response = $translationServiceClient->createGlossary($formattedParent, $glossary);
    $response->pollUntilComplete();
    if ($response->operationSucceeded()) {
        $result = $response->getResult();
        printf('Operation successful with response data: %s' . PHP_EOL, $result->serializeToJsonString());
    } else {
        $error = $response->getError();
        printf('Operation failed with error data: %s' . PHP_EOL, $error->serializeToJsonString());
    }
} catch (ApiException $ex) {
    printf('Call failed with message: %s' . PHP_EOL, $ex->getMessage());
}

Getting the term list and deleting the term list can be successful, but creating the term list cannot be successful.
The execution result prompt is:

Code 7
Message Error: PERMISSION_DENIED. Job state: FAILED.

The account permissions Iconfigured are:

Cloud Translation API Admin
DataCatalog Entry Owner - List item
DataCatalog Glossary User
Storage Admin
Storage Object Viewer

The project was working before,but suddenly on July 13th I can't create a glossary.Is there something wrong with my configuration?
I want to know how to deal with this problem.
This is the result returned：
{
"code": 7,
"message": "Error: PERMISSION_DENIED. Job state: FAILED.",
"details": [
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
"resourceType": "Cloud Storage file",
"resourceName": "gs://trans_text/translation5823.csv"
},
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
"detail": "generic::permission_denied: Calling Match with file "/bigstore/trans_text/translation5823.csv": generic::permission_denied: Calling GetObjectMetadata with file "/bigstore/trans_text/translation5823.csv": cloud.bigstore.ResponseCode.ErrorCode::ACCESS_DENIED: cloud-ml-translation-worker@prod.google.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist). cloud-ml-translation-worker@prod.google.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist). [google.rpc.error_details_ext] { message: "cloud-ml-translation-worker@prod.google.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission \'storage.objects.get\' denied on resource (or it may not exist)." details { [type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo] { stack_entries: "com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcClientException: APPLICATION_ERROR;cloud.bigstore/FrontendObjectsService.Get;cloud-ml-translation-worker@prod.google.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission \'storage.objects.get\' denied on resource (or it may not exist). cloud-ml-translation-worker@prod.google.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission \'storage.objects.get\' denied on resource (or it may not exist).;AppErrorCode=1;StartTimeMs=1721132267200;tcp;Deadline(sec)=9.992604092;ResFormat=uncompressed;interceptors={[com.google.cloud.bigstore.common.LatencyCollectingInterceptor;com.google.frameworks.debug.sherlog.core.rpcutil.Stubby3ClientInterceptor];overrides={}};ServerTimeSec=0.277276674;LogBytes=256;Non-FailFast;EffSecLevel=strong_privacy_and_integrity;ReqFormat=uncompressed;ReqID=1e86c8901c30e67b;GlobalID=fe5b6149cadcbe0b;Server=[::1]:14005" stack_entries: "com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub.startBlockingRpcInternal(RpcStub.java:571)" stack_entries: "com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub.startBlockingRpc(RpcStub.java:471)" stack_entries: "com.google.cloud.bigstore.proto.BackendObjectsService$Stub.get(BackendObjectsService.java:610)" stack_entries: "com.google.cloud.bigstore.api.common.LampreyServiceBase.call(LampreyServiceBase.java:56)" stack_entries: "com.google.cloud.bigstore.api.common.BigstoreFrontendObjectsServiceImpl.call(BigstoreFrontendObjectsServiceImpl.java:44)" stack_entries: "com.google.cloud.bigstore.api.common.BigstoreFrontendObjectsServiceImpl.get(BigstoreFrontendObjectsServiceImpl.java:81)" stack_entries: "com.google.cloud.bigstore.api.stubby.BigstoreStubbyImpl.lambda$getObjectMetadata$17(BigstoreStubbyImpl.java:1083)" stack_entries: "com.google.cloud.bigstore.api.common.CallbackRequestHandler.handleCallbackRequest(CallbackRequestHandler.java:276)" stack_entries: "com.google.cloud.bigstore.api.common.CallbackRequestHandler.handleCallbackRequest(CallbackRequestHandler.java:144)" stack_entries: "com.google.cloud.bigstore.api.stubby.BigstoreStubbyImpl.getObjectMetadata(BigstoreStubbyImpl.java:1071)" stack_entries: "com.google.cloud.bigstore.api.common.ProxyDelegatorBase.callAndRecordLatency(ProxyDelegatorBase.java:110)" stack_entries: "com.google.cloud.bigstore.api.stubby.StubbyProxyBase.call(StubbyProxyBase.java:159)" stack_entries: "com.google.cloud.bigstore.api.stubby.BigstoreStubbyProxy.getObjectMetadata(BigstoreStubbyProxy.java:403)" stack_entries: "com.google.cloud.bigstore.isolation.RpcReceiver.lambda$processRequestAsync$1(RpcReceiver.java:198)" stack_entries: "com.google.cloud.bigstore.isolation.AsyncExecutor.lambda$submit$0(AsyncExecutor.java:213)" stack_entries: "com.google.common.context.ContextRunnable.runInContext(ContextRunnable.java:83)" stack_entries: "io.grpc.Context.run(Context.java:536)" stack_entries: "com.google.tracing.GenericContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(GenericContextCallback.java:75)" stack_entries: "com.google.common.context.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:74)" stack_entries: "java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)" stack_entries: "java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)" stack_entries: "java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)" } } } [blobstore2.GcsErrorDetails] { xml_code: "AccessDenied" msg: "cloud-ml-translation-worker@prod.google.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission \'storage.objects.get\' denied on resource (or it may not exist)." http_code: 403 details { first: "Details" second: "cloud-ml-translation-worker@prod.google.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission \'storage.objects.get\' denied on resource (or it may not exist)." } debug_info: "cloud-ml-translation-worker@prod.google.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission \'storage.objects.get\' denied on resource (or it may not exist). cloud-ml-translation-worker@prod.google.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission \'storage.objects.get\' denied on resource (or it may not exist)." } [cloud.bigstore.GcsLatencyInfo] { requests { method: "/BackendObjectsService.Get" deadline { seconds: 9 nanos: 986781918 } start { seconds: 1721132267 nanos: 201421144 } end { seconds: 1721132267 nanos: 477976911 } status { code: 1 space: "cloud.bigstore.ResponseCode.ErrorCode" message: "cloud-ml-translation-worker@prod.google.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission \'storage.objects.get\' denied on resource (or it may not exist). cloud-ml-translation-worker@prod.google.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission \'storage.objects.get\' denied on resource (or it may not exist)." canonical_code: 7 } } requests { method: "/BucketMdService.LookupBucket" deadline { seconds: 4 nanos: 999962410 } start { seconds: 1721132267 nanos: 270744966 } end { seconds: 1721132267 nanos: 273039106 } status { } metadata_spanner_stats { read_walltime_millis: 0 read_cpu_millis: 0 read_scheduler_delay_millis: 0 read_throttle_delay_millis: 0 read_per_service_limit_queue_delay_millis: 0 read_locking_delay_millis: 0 read_client_overhead_delay_millis: 0 read_client_flow_control_delay_millis: 0 read_io_delay_millis: 0 } elapsed_time_isolator_metrics { } sunspot_verdict: VERDICT_CAT_UNKNOWN } requests { method: "/ObjectMdService.LookupObject" deadline { seconds: 4 nanos: 999962920 } start { seconds: 1721132267 nanos: 270744806 } end { seconds: 1721132267 nanos: 276720385 } status { } metadata_spanner_stats { read_walltime_millis: 0 read_cpu_millis: 0 read_scheduler_delay_millis: 0 read_throttle_delay_millis: 0 read_per_service_limit_queue_delay_millis: 0 read_locking_delay_millis: 0 read_client_overhead_delay_millis: 0 read_client_flow_control_delay_millis: 0 read_io_delay_millis: 0 slice_keys: "1:g5612_43043490" } elapsed_time_isolator_metrics { } sunspot_verdict: VERDICT_CAT_UNAVAILABLE } requests { method: "/AccessService.CheckGetObject" deadline { seconds: 9 nanos: 838916510 } start { seconds: 1721132267 nanos: 277024225 } end { seconds: 1721132267 nanos: 410471326 } status { } } slice_keys: "1:g5612_43043490" } [google.rpc.error_details_ext] { message: "cloud-ml-translation-worker@prod.google.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission \'storage.objects.get\' denied on resource (or it may not exist)." }; Match result: fail [google.rpc.error_details_ext] { message: "cloud-ml-translation-worker@prod.google.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission \'storage.objects.get\' denied on resource (or it may not exist)." }"
}
]
}

Please don't embed images in questions where it would be trivial to copy-paste the original text. Images may not outlive questions and make it more difficult for us to reference their content.

Please include the full stacktrace not just PERMISSION_DENIED. The context is useful.

It doesn't affect this issue but it is an anti-pattern (bad practice) to putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS={$secret_path}");. You should set the environment variable in the environment not in your code and before you run the code. The environment variable is only one way in which credentials are obtained by ADC. Please see Application Default Credentials (ADC)

Thank you for your answering this question.
The result returned is very long. I mainly extracted information such as code, message and detail.

I see a message in the returned object saying Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist)。
I don't know which permission I need to grant.
@DazWilkin

Thanks for updating your question with the full error message. Wow! That's possibly the most convoluted error message I've ever seen! I spent some time reformatting it to try to understand it. In summary the error is: "cloud-ml-translation-worker@prod.google.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission storage.objects.get denied on resource (or it may not exist)". However, this error appears to apply to a Google internal Service Account (cloud-ml-translation-worker@prod.google.com) and not your credentials. Does the error continue?

I rewrote your PHP sample in Go and I see the same error. It's either the approach in our code or -- more likely -- this is an error with the Google service. In Go, it surfaces /bigstore/ error messages. I also tried making the Service Account owner which should confer every role that it needs and this makes no difference.

Yes, this problem has lasted for five or six days and is now waiting to be resolved@DazWilkin

I had the same problem, just add storage.objects.get permissions to the cloud-ml-translation-worker@prod.google.com account on the IAM service.
E.g.
PROJECT="..."
USER="cloud-ml-translation-worker@prod.google.com"
ROLE="roles/storage.objectViewer"

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=user:${USER} \
--role=${ROLE}

roles/storage.objectViewer is one of the predefined IAM roles for Cloud Storage that includes storage.objects.get

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This solution works but it is very curious. In my experience, I've never encountered a solution in which a Google user account (cloud-ml-translation-worker@prod.google.com) must be policy bound to a Project.

I think this is an issue on Google Cloud, but I couldn't find any relevant information in the official documentation. Since my account doesn't have support access, I can't contact Google to find out the exact reason.
